# Which UML editor is this? Alternatively, how can I view and edit this diagram (XML file)?

Tags: uml, editor

A couple of years ago I worked on a project and thus I prepared some UML diagrams. Now I have the XML files but I can't remember the editor I used to create them. Can you help me in finding it?
I use Kubuntu.
here you can find an old
[screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4nOH7xkcKiaSDBtUlZ4X0NjY2c) and an [XML file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4nOH7xkcKiaSE9jOHlFYmRyTXc)

EDIT: I'm almost sure it was a free tool for linux. Nevertheless, any (free) editor that can open the XML files I have in my HD would be a satisfactory answer for me!

Comment: looks like **astah** to me - i was using it before, it was called **JUDE** in the past

Comment: I'm almost sure it was a free tool, because I never spent money for a UML editor, as far as I remember. Unfortunately, it seems that the XML file does not contain any hint about the editor...

Comment: it is a free tool - at least in some respects: http://astah.net/editions/community

Comment: I see. However, the installation procedure on Linux still looks too difficult http://astah.net/faq/professional/how-to-run-astah-on-linux. I think I chose something Linux-ready. I will give a try, but I'm skeptical

Comment: Google for mxfile

Comment: Now I can see the code, more or less. How can this help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Analysing the code I saw that "mx" was a recurring prefix. Googling the name of the XML entities I could see in the code, I found that they are described in mxGraph’s diagramming API. Finally, I found an online tool that uses mxGraph: "draw.io". Many thanks to Thomas Kilian!
Now, next question could be how to save the diagrams in a standard format for future use without going crazy again...